# Selenium unable to locate element, perhaps anti-selenium detection?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If I use a Chrome or Firefox driver, I keep getting:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#id-of-element"}
>     (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (long hex code here),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

I went to the same webpage and stored it locally. When I pointed the webdriver to the local file it could locate the input element and fill it with `SendKeys`

Is it possible that the online version of the website has some sort of protection for selenium? like distil?

I have also tried to get the element by id or xpath. I has a wait and I have used these extension methods:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            //return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            //return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElements(by);
    }
}
```

Firefox gives less info:

> Unable to locate element #id-of-element

Comment: I think it's more possible the data you are seeking for is Javascript content, when you save a page from a browser the saved page is the result _after_ executing the javascript initial scripts, which can dynamically add content to it.

Comment: Probably the `id` of that element is changing every time. Cross check if the element `id` is static. If not don't `findelement` by `id`.

Comment: Id is the same everytime. And Gusman, I wait for the js event when page is complete and when jquery is loaded. So dynamically added content should be searchable? I also tried `var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('id-of-element').setAttribute(....`